# Parse Table Generator for Simple Precedence Parsing

Tags: java, parsing, compiler-construction

I have been assigned a compiler project for a mini-Pascal language. The project enforce the use of  '**Simple Precedence**' as parsing algorithm but allows us to use **parse table generator tools** for creating the parse table.

Does anyone now such a **parse table generator**? I have tried searching for one myself but haven't found anything useful yet.

I am writing the program in Java so it would be best if the generator results were in Java, but C/C++ will also be useful. (I am in a bit of a hurry...)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this book. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools and don't be hurry, because this subject takes time

Comment: @Leo:  Thanks but that's actually our reference textbook for the course. It doesn't cover Simple Precedence. I know how it should work but what I'm actually looking for is a "code"/"program" which generates the parse table for the given algorithm. I have to hurry because I have a deadline to catch and that's why I need the generator. If I had time I would have implemented it myself.